# I hyperlinked a cell in excel 2003, formula issues?

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, microsoft-excel-2003, worksheet-function

I have a budget spreadsheet using excel 2003. I have My deposit, then all of my bills, the total, then a cell that has the difference(between the amount of deposit and the total of the bills). The difference cell numbers turn red when I dont have enough money (deposit vs bill total).

I hyperlinked the difference cell to a checkbook register spreadsheet so I can track where all my extra money went(reconsile receipts daily). When hyperlinked the numbers are blue. I need the numbers to stay black(when above 0.00) and stay red (when the numbers are below 0.00) and not change after the link has been clicked on.

Also if the link has not been clicked on, and the numbers are red, the font is smaller, even though the toolbar shows the font size hasnt changed. After I click on it and go back to the budget sheet, its the size it should be.

Any Ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This article explains the idea:

http://faqica.blogspot.com/2007/09/excel-hyperlink-color-colours.html

However in your case you want to modify the colors to "Automatic" and change the font size.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer! I guess Excel was being buggy because it worked on other sheets in the workbook. I had Conditional Formatting on those cells and I ended up right clicking on the cell, format cells|font: underline=none and color+automatic. The Conditional formatting is still a little buggy because it wont let me change the font size or style. Is there a formula that can be used instead of conditional formatting?